# Rails and queries - Custom query to get duplicated records

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

For the most part I try not to write custom SQL queries with my apps but I came acros a case and I was wondering if this would be one those cases where I would be better off doing it.

I'm using PostgreSQL with this specific app. I want to return only employees that have been double booked for a task here are my models.

I have the following models bellow.

User

```
has_many :user_jobs

    Fields
    - id
    - name
    - address
    - phone
```

Jobs

```
has_many :user_jobs
has_many :users, through: :user_jobs

    Fields
    - id
    - date
    - start_time
    - end_time
```

UserJobs

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :jobs

    Fields
    - id
    - job_id
    - user_id
```

Userjobs is the table that holds the jobs and employees for that job but the date and time of each job is saved in the Job table

I would like to return something like

`user(employee) - date and time job1 - date and time job1`

EDIT: added more schema detail

```
CREATE TABLE user_jobs (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    job_id integer,
    job_date date,
    notes text,
    job_rating integer,
    notes text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    user_id integer,
);


CREATE TABLE jobs (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    date date,
    start_time time without time zone,
    end_time time without time zone,
    notes text,
);


CREATE TABLE users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    email character varying(255) DEFAULT ''::character varying NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    address character varying(255),
    phone character varying(255),
    picture character varying(255),
    status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'active'::character varying,
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? I also didn't understand what you're actually trying to do here. What exactly you're looking for?

Comment: I had not tried anything serious but a bunch of joint queries to see if I could get at least all the data first. What I'm trying to accomplish is to list all Employees that have been double booked. I'll take a look at the response provided by @xavier-shay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Postgres 9.2+**

It's kind of a gnarly query:

```
WITH alljobs AS(
  SELECT * FROM jobs j INNER JOIN user_jobs uj ON uj.job_id = j.id
) 
SELECT DISTINCT q1.user_id
FROM alljobs q1
JOIN alljobs q2 on
      q1.user_id = q2.user_id
  AND tsrange(q1.date + q1.start_time, q1.date + q1.end_time) && tsrange(q2.date + q2.start_time, q2.date + q2.end_time)
```

Explanation:

- **`WITH alljobs`** effectively assigns the variable name `alljobs` to the given query. That query is just a joined list of all job assignments with start and end times.
- **`SELECT DISTINCT q1.user_id`** returns only IDs of users that are double booked. This is technically what you asked for, though you'll likely want to expand this select to get back more useful information. I'd recommend using `SELECT *` while debugging.
- **`FROM alljobs q1 JOIN alljobs q2`** This joins the assignments against itself, which is necessary to compare each assignment to every other assignment.
- **`q1.user_id = q2.user_id`** We only care about collisions for a single user. You could alter this if you wanted to answer related questions such as "who is working together?"
- **`tsrange`** a [postgres built-in range function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) that creates a range from two timestamps. There a similar functions for dates and other types of timestamps. _These range types were only introduced in 9.2.
- **`&&`** a [postgres range operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html) for intersection.

**Postgres <9.2**

You can replace `tsrange` and `&&` with your own intersection logic, which I think looks something like: `q1.start_time < q2.start_time && q1.finish_time > q2.start_time OR q2.start_time < q1.start_time && q2.finish_time > q1.start_time`. (Add in `date` as well.)

Or, since you specified start time is always the same, and that's really all you care about, you can do something simpler in that case:

```
SELECT user_id, date + start_time, COUNT(*)
FROM user_jobs INNER JOIN jobs ON job_id = jobs.id
GROUP BY user_id, date + start_time
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

That will give you all user IDs that have duplicates. To get the respective jobs, you can wrap that in an outer query.

```
SELECT user_jobs.user_id, user_jobs.job_id, jobs.date + jobs.start_time
FROM user_jobs INNER JOIN jobs ON job_id = jobs.id INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, date + start_time, COUNT(*)
  FROM user_jobs INNER JOIN jobs ON job_id = jobs.id
  GROUP BY user_id, date + start_time
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) dups ON dups.user_id = user_jobs.user_id
      AND dups.date + dups.start_time = job.date + jobs.start_time
```

**Schema Suggestion**

You're making life more difficult for yourself by having separate `date` and `time` columns. Why not just make `start_time` and `end_time` timestamps? Then you don't always need to be adding them together, and you can still get the date by casting it.

Comment: Thanks Xavier. I'll give a try and update my post here.

Comment: I keep getting this error: `Error : ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer == integer
LINE 5: ...alljobs q1 JOIN alljobs q2 ON q1.user_id::integer == q2.user...` I even tried to add ::interger to make sure I was type casting correctly

Comment: sorry typo, try a single `=`.

Comment: almost there... I got this error with sigle equal sign `Error : ERROR:  function tsrange(time without time zone) does not exist`

Comment: I have tried this `AND tsrange(q1.start_time::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) && tsrange(q2.start_time::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)` but I get the same error

Comment: what version of postgres are you on? What is the type of your column start_time? Did you type it in exactly - that error looks like you're only passing one param to tsrange, where it needs two: both the start and end times. Can you try the following: `select tsrange(NOW()::timestamp, NOW()::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 day')` and `select tsrange(start_time, end_time) from jobs;`?

Comment: The "date" field type is date and "start_time" is time. I tried the query above and got the following error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: ...mestamp, NOW()::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 day') and select tsr...` I see that you are using a range between start and end.... but I just need to check if 2 or more jobs start at the same time and date for the employee. Since they work on block of hours if they start at the same time they are most likely double booked

Comment: can you post your full session to https://gist.github.com, and also include a schema dump `pg_dump mydb -t mytable --schema-only`. I'm not sure what's going wrong but full context will assist.

Comment: Thanks again Xavie... I added more schema detail on my original post above and here is the gist for the query https://gist.github.com/mpaulopes/e5716906a9b67c81e598

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69325/discussion-between-xavier-shay-and-marrento).

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I was typing my last message about start date I realized I did not need the date field. I made the adjustment to the query and everything works fine.